# When producer raise NotEnoughReplicas in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka doc [min.insync.replicas](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_min.insync.replicas) say:

> When a producer sets acks to "all" (or "-1"), min.insync.replicas specifies the minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write for the write to be considered successful. If this minimum cannot be met, then the producer will raise an exception (either NotEnoughReplicas or NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppend).
> When used together, min.insync.replicas and acks allow you to enforce greater durability guarantees. A typical scenario would be to create a topic with a replication factor of 3, set min.insync.replicas to 2, and produce with acks of "all". This will ensure that the producer raises an exception if a majority of replicas do not receive a write.

But in my understanding, it is not clear when the Producer will raise an `NotEnoughReplicas`  exception.

## My two questions：

1. Does the Producer raise the exception immediately when the number of ISR queues is less than that value and aks=all, or does it wait for a timeout?
2. When the Producer receives this error, it is also able to retry if the [retries](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_retries) does not reach the maximum value？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the request has been sent to the leader broker it writes into its leader partition and then the follower brokers will replicate that message. The followers must then acknowledge the message write.

This whole process (including replication) must complete within the producer timeout configured by `request.timeout.ms` parameter and this `request.timeout.ms` must be **larger** than the `replica.lag.time.max.ms` (broker config, which is the time after which the leader will remove a broker from the ISR).

If a follower broker is removed from the ISR after the message is appended to the log, then you get the `NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppendException`. If it before appending to the log, then you get `NotEnoughReplicasException`. In either case, retries happen till `delivery.timeout.ms`.

If your `request.timeout.ms` elapses before getting acknowledgement from all the replicas in the ISR, then it is retried till max retries is hit or `delivery.timeout.ms` is elapsed.

> Does the Producer raise the exception immediately when the number of
> ISR queues is less than that value and aks=all, or does it wait for a
> timeout?

There is a timeout (`request.timeout.ms`)  till which it will wait for the acknowledgement.

> When the Producer receives this error, it is also able to retry if the
> retries does not reach the maximum value？

Retries happen, both `NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppendException` and `NotEnoughReplicasException` are `RetriableException`s.

Comment: Nice, `If it before appending to the log, then you get NotEnoughReplicasException`